# Flutter build fail

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

stack overflow community I'm asking for help. well this my first project my school project I got this error while my project was running and i tried all videos on youtube that might solve my problem but it didn't help i really hope that u might help me tp solve my problem please its important

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\nouhaila\AndroidStudioProjects\elearning\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. Current version is 5.6.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\nouhaila\AndroidStudioProjects\elearning\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.5-all.zip

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: It says you need to upgrade Gradle.

Comment: Please read your error message. A lot of information is stored in there, sometimes pinpointing to the line and character where the error happened - for future errors

Answer (score 0):

Looks like duplicate of [repo](http://You%20could%20just%20edit%20YOUR_APPLICATION_FOLDER/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties%20and%20change%20the%20last%20line%20to:%20distributionUrl=https%5C://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip%20Android%20Studio%20will%20download%20necessary%20library.). You could just edit YOUR_APPLICATION_FOLDER/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change the last line to: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip Android Studio will download necessary library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to update gradle version.
My solution is to change
`"distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-bin.zip "` =>
`"distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip "` in  `gradle-wrapper.properties`